# How do I set the .Content property outside of MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

In MainWindow.xaml.cs, I normally do:

```
this.Content = new MyPage();
```

where MyPage was created in the visual designer as a WPF page.

That works fine, but how do I set the main window's content to another page from inside MyPage.xaml.cs?

Thanks.

Comment: find main window's reference, then set another page, what's the difficulties?

Comment: Use `Application.Current.MainWindow.Content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, you need to get a reference to the application's main window. You do that with the following code:

```
var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Then you can set its content directly as you would from within "MainWindow.xaml.cs":

```
mainWindow.Content = new Page1();
```

If you need to get or set something specific to your window implementation, you can cast the object you get from the above method:

```
var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MyWindow;

if (mainWindow != null)
    mainWindow.MyProperty = someValue;
```

(where `MyWindow` is the name of your main window's class and `MyProperty` is some property defined in that class.)

---

Alternatively, you can create a static [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) of your main window that you initialize in the constructor:

```
public static readonly MyWindow Singleton;

public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (Singleton == null)
        Singleton = this;
}
```

Then you can access it just as you would a static property:

```
MyWindow.Singleton.MyProperty = someValue;
```

This approach has the benefit of being able to be used on other windows as well.

(I'd only recommend this on windows that will only be opened once over the lifetime of your program, however. If you have a separate window that will have multiple instances created of it, then the `Singleton` will only be set for the first one.)

Comment: I guess I can set some properties in MainWindow like you suggest.  Thank you!